# Retrieve XPath of an XML element by using its value

Tags: xml, xml-serialization

My XmlFile looks like this:

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <document-inquiry>
    <publication-reference data-format="docdb" xmlns="http://www.epo.org/exchange">
      <document-id>
        <country>EP</country>
        <doc-number>2160088</doc-number>
        <kind>A1</kind>
      </document-id>
    </publication-reference>

  </document-inquiry>`

For the above xml i need to get the xpath of a specific element say for example "country element" as

My Output: **"/document-inquiry/publication-reference/document-id/country"**

My Input : By using its value **"EP"**

This is the code i tried

```
doc.SelectSingleNode("/document-inquiry/publication-reference/document-id[text()='EP']");
```

I receivev null for the above code.

I have to get it using the c# code. Can anyone pls help me on this

Comment: Why the #$$# would you use capital letters in your title?

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load("D:\\xml\\neo.xml");
        var ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
        ns.AddNamespace("ns", "http://www.epo.org/exchange");
        var elem = XDocument.Load("D:\\xml\\neo.xml")
            .XPathSelectElement("//ns:document-id[ns:doc-number='1000']", ns);
        if (elem != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(elem.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly for me.

Comment: Bump. Looks like you're not registering the custom namespace. This would happen in other (non-dotNET) implementations as well.